# Delete multiple objects in NHibernate 3.2

Tags: lambda, expression, predicate, nhibernate-3

In my `Repository` I have a method like this:

```
public int Delete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) {
    var listToDelete = UnitOfWork.Session.Query<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList();
    foreach(var item in listToDelete)
        UnitOfWork.Session.Delete(item);
    return listToDelete.Count;
}
```

But it seems this method has not a good performance! Have you any suggestion for delete a list of objects (by a predicate) in `NHibernate 3.2` please?

Answer (score 2):

Use `IStatelessSession` to delete or update multiple objects. It will be faster because the identity map will not slow down the session/operations.

You can also use HQL queries for batch operations.

Comment: I'm new to NHibernate; can you show me an example please? Thanks

Comment: Stateless session: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/30/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernate-s-stateless-sessions.aspx